# Does terminating glfw and closing any open windows destroy any opengl contexts using said windows?

Tags: opengl, glfw

Does calling:

```
glfwTerminate();
glfwDestroyWindow(windowID);
```

terminate any glfw contexts which were using the now closed windows?

Comment: FYI: You shouldn't [make any GLFW calls *after* `glfwTerminate`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__init.html#gaaae48c0a18607ea4a4ba951d939f0901), with the exception of `glfwInit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

> [Window objects](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_object): The GLFWwindow object encapsulates both a window **and a context**. They are created with glfwCreateWindow and destroyed with glfwDestroyWindow, **or glfwTerminate**, if any remain.

Comment: Note that no contexts can be current when you call `glfwTerminate`.

Comment: how would i make sure no contexts are current - I don't think i'm doing this currently

Comment: @Edward: Call `glfwMakeContextCurrent(NULL)` on every thread where `glfwGetCurrentContext()` returns non-NULL.